# Cannot run javadoc from console at java 10

Tags: java, javadoc, maven-javadoc-plugin

I'm trying to get javadocs for my classes directly from console with following code `javadoc -sourcepath ./src/main java.packageName`. Those classes have dependencies on external libraries (e.g `junit.framework`). This code is easy to compile from IntelliJ IDEA or via `mvn clean install`, but when I'm trying to create javadocs I face the problem that external classes and packages cannot be recognized (e.g. `error: package junit.framework does not exist`). Same problem occurs with JDK 8 as well, but there those are warnings and javadocs are generated anyway.

Comment: Why not use Maven to generate the Javadoc? https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/

Comment: maven javadoc plugin usage is here if you decide to go that route instead (as @Slaw suggests): https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/usage.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two approaches you could take to get the javadocs to build from the command line:

- Add the maven-javadoc-plugin to your project's POM file so that you can use (for example) `mvn javadoc:javadoc` to generate the javadocs.  See the [plugin documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/usage.html) for more details.
- Run `javadoc` directly with the *correct* command-line arguments.

I suspect that there are a couple of reasons why your current attempt is failing:

- You appear to be generating javadocs for your `src/test` tree.  That may be unintentional.

  (If the above "error: ..." is coming from the `src/main` javadoc generation, I'm puzzled why your `src/main` source code is referring to the `junit.framework` package.  It could do, but production code wouldn't normally depend on a test framework.)
- You need to use a `-classpath` option to tell `javadoc` where to find the external libraries are.

Comment: That was about `-classpath`. It seems we need to manually pass all class paths

Answer (score 1):

"This code is easy to compile from intellij" just use the JavaDoc function from intellij. It should work

Tools - Generate JavaDoc

Comment: Well it works, but I need to know how to do it directly from console. It will be run from sh scripts

Comment: I see, well then i'd also suggest to use maven as @Slaw wrote.